# is there an API in VSCode WebView Extension to download a file from a uri string?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview, download, uri, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension to VSCode and i'm trying to download a file from a uri string with a suggested file name.
this is usually done on the browsers in a way that doesn't work in the extension.

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
}
```

then call it:

```
downloadURI("data:text/html,HelloWorld!", "helloWorld.txt");
```

How this should be written for vscode extension webview?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of handling the download in the webview send a message to your extension with the selected file name and use Node.js (or axios, or whatever you prefer) in the extension to get the file. This has the additional advantage that you are allowed to store the file everywhere, while in a browser context you can store a file only in a the set download location.